# VSCode Remote-Container extension ignore my .dockerignore file

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers, dockerignore

**Development Environment:**

- VSCode Version: 1.69.2 (system setup)
- Local OS Version: Windows 11 Pro. version 21H2
- Remote OS Version: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
- Remote Extension/Connection Type: SSH/Containers/WSL/Server
- Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
- Issue #7007 on 31 Jul: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7007

*VSCode Remote-Container extension ignore my .dockerignore file:*

For some strange reason my .dockerignore is being ignored. **Why??? ...is there a solution???** ***...thxs***

example repo: https://github.com/bonaccipp/Remote-Containers-ignore-my-.dockerignore.git

[Example image with: Dockerfile, devcontainer.json and dockerignore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93BgT.png)

Comment: no, I haven't found a solution... meanwhile, and to get ahead in my project: I detached the Database from docker, but in the future I know I'll run into the same problem